# Handling "null reference warnings" in .Net Core 7 with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use .Net Core 7, Entity Framework and the Controller <-> Service <-> Repository <-> DBContext Pattern.

I have a method that shows an warning

```
public Person Get(Guid id)
{
    // Returns a Person on find, null on a miss
    return db.Person.SingleOrDefault(id);
}
```

My approach would be to change the method to:

```
public Person? Get(Guid id)
{
    // Returns a Person on find, null on a miss
    return db.Person.SingleOrDefault(id);
}
```

In the **service** I would check if the person is null and if so throw an exception.

In the controller, I would catch the exception and throw NotFoundResult, for example.

Is this a clean approach?

Comment: [Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

Comment: Why not just return `null` from the service and translate that into a `NotFound` in your API?

Comment: Exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances. Usually, not finding an item in the database is not exceptional .

Comment: If you don't like `null` (which I can sympathize with) you may be interested in solutions like "OneOf" (not affiliated) which gives you an approximation to discriminated unions.